# Функция не выводит массив

Tags: javascript

Пишу функцию "f5", которая принимает массив как параметр и выводит его в формате указанном в функции в указанный блок(как второй параметр).

```
function f5(arr, block) {
    let out = '';

    for (let key in arr) {
        out += `${key} : ${arr[key]} <br>`;
    }

    return block;
}

document.querySelector('.b-5').onclick = () => {
    let a5 = {
        "one": 1,
        "two": 2
    };

    f5(a5, '.out-5');
};
```

Но этот код не работает. Не выводит результат в .out-5. Почему?

Comment: И где она его «выводит»?

Comment: В .out-5 это div элемент. Должен показываться на браузере.

Comment: "Не выводит результат в .out-5. Почему?" --- потому что ты нигде не используешь методы для вывода в HTML?  Вот что по-твоему должна значить запись `return '.out-5';` ?

Comment: покажи в своем коде место, где ты получаешь этот элемент и выводишь в него какие-нибудь данные

Comment: Оно отсутствует. Не знаю как правильно написать вывод.

Comment: `'.out-5'` это просто строка. Я не вижу в коде как из неё получается `div` и как что-то в этот `div` выводится.

Comment: @Asylbek возвращай не строку, а элемент по этому классу и присваивай ему текст return document.querySelector(block).innerHTML=out;

Comment: Спасибо сработало. Но до этого я сам догадался, но оно сработало. Оказывается нужно писать до return block;

Answer (score -1):

1. Находите в функции переданный элемент по селектору
2. Вставляете в найденный элемент содержимое `out`. Для этого можете использовать свойство innerHTML или метод insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте минимальный код для воспроизведения.

Comment: @WalkMess автор уже выше в комментариях отписался что сделал. Вчера мне уважаемые люди сделали замечение, чтобы я не давал пример кода на очевидные ответы, а только подсказки - чтобы люди сами пробовали, а не копипастили